# Is it unreasonable to demand a signed and executed contract before quitting a job and extend my agreed upon start date past then?

Tags: professionalism, canada

I have a verbal offer, but so far it has taken the company a week to generate the offer letter and I keep being told that "it is coming. HR is just slow." My problem was that I agreed to start Monday the week after next on the assumption that the offer letter and contract would be signed imminently after a verbal acceptance (I have never waited more than an hour before).

I had that conversation last Friday. I still don't have so much as a welcome email, yet alone an offer package. I had assumed I would resign Monday.

Am I wrong to say that I am moving my start date to some point after I sign some documents?  I don't want to quit a job before they actually formally agree that they are hiring me.

I have a verbal and the guy seemed nice, but that doesn't seem like enough.

On the one hand I didn't make this condition initially clear, but I also assumed (and have always gotten) very prompt offer letters.

Comment: What country / state?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without a location tag. In my country, every sentence you wrote is a direct contradiction of what we normally do. But telling you that is not helpful, is it? So please, add a location/country tag and maybe mention the industry too.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Ontario, Canada

Comment: @nvoigt Ontario, in Canada. I am a software dev.

Comment: Just in case you are not aware, verbal contracts are binding in Canada, though it may be worthwhile to wait for a written contract to be delivered.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Enforcing any kind of employment contract dispute can take years if not a decade in the Ontario courts.  If you don't have a written contract, and there is a dispute, it could take a long time and have uncertain outcome.  You might win the court case, but that won't help you pay your bills for the next few years.  And if the business goes under while your case goes through the system, your claim will be in line behind every secured creditor, so you'll get pennies on the dollar.  There is a large difference between "law is on your side" and "you can rely on the law to defend you"

Comment: The trick about verbal contracts is that proving what was said is hard.  Written contracts might easily lead to disputes about what the words mean, and that's with the exact words in print.

Comment: You never waited more than _one hour_ for a contract after verbal acceptance? Is Canada such a paragon of efficiency? What I heard from many places all over the world waiting some days or even a week is totally the expected norm.

Answer (score 89):

Just get in touch with them and say that the start date will need to be moved backwards to give you enough time to review and make your arrangements.

No need to make a big deal of it.

People are going to claim that a week is way too long. Some may even claim it's a "red flag". But the reality is that different companies have different challenges. This company may have a HR team that is very slow to get things sorted.

I have worked for a company where this was the case, and it's absolutely just as frustrating as a hiring manager, because you don't want the new employee to think they are undervalued, and you want them in the company as soon as possible.

Comment: IDK if I'd call it a red flag, but definitely a yellow flag. And if you start a new position without an offer letter, you don't have anything to fall back on if they try to change the conditions. Definitely move the start date until after signing the offer and don't even hint to the current employer that you are leaving, since that might be "cause for termination" for some companies. It unfortunately is here in the US.

Comment: It may not be a red flag, but I've dropped companies from consideration often enough after being too sluggish to respond in time (which always was multiple weeks for something that didn't have to take two days). Never be afraid to walk away from a company if you feel a bad hiring process is just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: @Mast Well, I'd say be afraid if you really need the job. In my experience the HR process is quite divorced from the regular day-to-day process, so I'm not sure how much a sluggish HR process shows.

Comment: In my experience a week for the full offer (for a permanent position) would be pretty quick!

Comment: A week is nothing. The time between my niece being orally told she got her government job and getting the formal offer was several months. But she loves the job.

Answer (score 64):

Never quit a job for another job without a concrete offer for the new job in hand.

Too many things can go wrong between the promise and your actual offer.  Things that might go wrong:

- Drug test failure
- Background check problem
- I-9 issues (USA work eligibility as citizen or authorized non-citizen)
- Company restructuring
- Company events (lost a major customer, plant blew up, etc.)
- New boss wants to hire their nephew

Comment: Yes. Regardless of what the law may say. If the law gets involved, things take time and you never get that back. CYA up front always!

Comment: Except for the times when quitting before having a new job in hand is actually the better thing to do.

Comment: Until the agreement is signed by both parties, either can easily renege. Always acceptable to push back the start date by a reasonable time (one to four weeks depending) due to HR's recognized busyness. Professional curtesy notice is two weeks — the newly signed contract may require a mandatory notification time period and you may be under the same for the current company.

Comment: To be fair, in lots of jurisdictions either side can cancel the work contract during the first month without any warning or repercussions. The company could also go bankrupt the very same day you join. So there is no 100% safety.

Comment: @Michael True. The company I worked in once had a major restructure and a lot of layoff due to covid. Some of the newhires are laid off on day 2 of work.

Comment: @Michael in some jurisdictions (like Germany) you are just screwed if you terminate a position without a signed contract as you are then opt-out of unemployment benefits which could pay your bills in case the new company turns you down immediately.

TL;DR Never ever terminate a position in Germany without a new contract.

Comment: @justhalf, I met a guy who started at a company (in the UK), and between signing the contract and starting the job the whole department hiring him had been laid off, including the hiring manager. He arrived at the company and nobody still working there knew about him. Walked around until he found a manager who needed work to be done, and stayed at the company for six years :-)

Comment: @gnasher729 Wow, what a first day for that worker, haha. Good for him that he found something to be done.

Comment: Absolutely this.  I had a verbal offer from a company that was pretty good.  Said I'd wait for an offer letter.  Called back after 5 days of no letter.  The company had restructured suddenly, and the guy that made the offer was gone.  *ALWAYS* get it in writing!

Answer (score 4):

You'd never hand in your notice at your old company without having an enforcable contract in your hand with the new company.

This means in the USA with 14 days notice, you can start at the earliest 14 days after the contract is in your hand. In Europe, your notice period can be a lot longer. The exception is of course if you are unemployed and can start at any second. You can actually reasonably safely start work before you have your contract (you would have an implied contract).

Comment: As far as I'm aware, 14 days is only a convention that is the minimum "polite" period to leave without burning bridges. You can leave any time in at will employment, with the understanding that you may not be welcome back if you don't do it politely. In OP's case it seems that 14 days would be a good idea. Not sure what the convention is in Canada though.

Comment: most job offers in the US are not "enforceable."

Answer (score 0):

It seems the usual dirty tactic. They will send you the contract at the very last moment in order to force you to take a decision without having enough time to read proprerly the new contract or seek some advice. Take it as a red flag, usually in this situations the contract will respect the initial offer, but hidden in the contract there might be some unfair clauses. E.G. If you work in IT you might find excessive clauses for non competition or intellectual property.

If you you can delay the agreed date, for the beginning of the new job, do it immediately. But in this case the other side might also find an excuse to delay the preparation of the contract. If you have a couple of trusted friends who can help you read the contract put them on alert, you could divide the contract in blocks an each of you read thoroughly a single block.

One thing you could do is lie about the notice period, you can say that you remembered that there is a special clause in your contract that requires a longer notice period. E.G. The notice can start only at the beginning of the month, but can end only on a Friday. In this way they will be forced to give you the contract few days before your deadline for the resignation.

Answer (score -24):

Ask for a signing bonus.  If they really want you, they can put some serious money in your hands right now.  They can structure it as a forgivable loan.  If you show up and work for them for a certain number of months they forgive the loan.  If they don't hire you or they fire you, they also forgive the loan.

Comment: Very aggressive move, considering the particulars have already been agreed upon.

Comment: this would get you kicked to the curb at my company.

Comment: If the company is being honorable but slow, this is just going to insult them. If the company is evil and trying something, this just gives them more ways to screw you over. Either way, I wouldn't advise it.

Comment: @TigerGuy It would be better for OP to be "kicked to the curb" before OP gives notices to current employer because OP asked for a signing bonus than OP to be "kicked to the curb" after OP give notice because the budget shifted.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad _option_ to have for negotiation in the case the new company insists on starting without giving a contract or such.   Maybe it would be better expressed as such specifically.

Comment: @MikeM. If the new company insists on that, run. They won't give you a bonus large enough to compensate for the hurt they are planning for you.

Comment: @MadPhysicist If the company pays you a signing bonus they probably want you to work for them and if they don't then you will have income while you look for a new job.  If the company does not pay you a signing bonus, then it will cost them nothing to fire you before your first day.  Reorganizations happen all the time.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Regardless a signing bonus of $1BILLION can compensate for any hurt they are planning for you.  So there is a bonus large enough.

Comment: I totally agree, which is why I specifically phrased it as "They won't give you...". If they do, you can be pretty certain it's not in good faith.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think where this can come in handy is when you are dealing with a multi-layer company.  Every individual is acting rationally but the company as a whole might make irrational decisions.  One layer wants to hire OP, but a couple layers higher they are thinking about shutting down entire departments.